# Show Content if below specific width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I know how to HIDE Content using css, if width is below certain px. Like attatched to the Broser side Social Logos. But i do wish to have them hidden, as long the browser shows the Layout in it's proper Desktop version, but show it if it gets Tablet/Mobile layout? Secondary, would new devices like the Kindle HD Fire with their HUGH resolution won't be a problem if it comes to that solution anyways? Is there maybe a better way to avoid that?
I could never really understand how these responsive frameworks are doing it, so maybe there is a more 'save'solution? Help is really appreciated.

Comment: Media Queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Media queries are the way to go.  To hide only on larger resolutions, switch `max-width` with `min-width` or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media queries is the only solution to it. Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bn48vLk/

Try changing the width of the result section.

**HTML:**

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="big" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="small" />
```

**CSS:**

```
.small {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width:400px) {
    .small {
        display: block;
    }
    .big {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfectly, seems like thats what i was looking for, easier than i had thought. Just changing min/max i wouldn't had thought about, seemed to be too easy :)